# Kohana Route Issue To Base URL

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

I am using Kohana 3.3

### **Goal**

I would like to have my application select the proper view file based on the language in the URL. So for example:

`mydomain.com/es/foobar` would load the Spanish view file in my Foobar controller. This is working for anything but the base URL. Right now if you go to `mydomain.com/es/` or `mydomain.com/en/` I am getting a 404 returned. I would like for it to route to the Index controller at `/classes/Controller/Index.php` I am not sure what I am missing here. Any pointers would be appreciated.

NOTE:

`mydomain.com` correctly gets directed to the english language page.

I can post some Controller code if necessary but I am fairly certain this is just a routing problem.

### **Current Routes**

```
/*I don't think this one is even getting fired even though it's first */
Route::set('mydomain_home', '(<lang>/)',
array(
    'lang' => '(en|es)'
))
->filter(function($route, $params, $request)
{   
    $lang = is_empty($params['lang']) ? 'en' : $params['lang'];
    /*This debug statement is not printing*/
    echo Debug::vars('Language in route filter: '.$lang);
    $params['controller'] = $lang.'_Index';
    return $params; // Returning an array will replace the parameters
})
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'Index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'lang' => 'en',
));;

/*This one works for the non-base URL e.g. mydomain.com/es/page1 */
Route::set('mydomain_default', '(<lang>/)(<controller>(/<action>(/<subfolder>)))',
array(
    'lang' => '(en|es)',
))
->filter(function($route, $params, $request) {
        // Replacing the hyphens for underscores.
        $params['action'] = str_replace('-', '_', $params['action']);
        return $params; // Returning an array will replace the parameters.
})
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'Index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'lang' => 'en',
));
```

Comment: Can't you use kohanas build in I18n module? Using different view files for different languages would be impossible to maintain. http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/I18n

Comment: Are you using different controllers for different languages??? If I were you I'd seriously consider something else. There should not even be any output in the controllers, so those should NEVER have to be localized.

Comment: @AmazingDreams Using separate view files is no different than using the I18N. Whenever anything changes I have to go hunt down that particular bunch of text and change it. I also plan on the HTML structure diverging between language-specific versions of the website, so it makes sense. Do you have anything to add about my actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your problem and used your routes. After modifying them I came to the conclusion two routes would be easier. One for the normal URLs and one for the language routes.

Below are the routes I made:

```
Route::set('language_default', '(<lang>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<subfolder>))))',
array(
    'lang' => '(en|es)',
))
->filter(function($route, $params, $request) {
    // Replacing the hyphens for underscores.
    $params['action'] = str_replace('-', '_', $params['action']);
    return $params; // Returning an array will replace the parameters.
})
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'Index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'lang' => 'en',
));


Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<subfolder>)))')
->filter(function($route, $params, $request) {
    // Replacing the hyphens for underscores.
    $params['action'] = str_replace('-', '_', $params['action']);
    return $params; // Returning an array will replace the parameters.
})
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'Index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'lang' => 'en',
));
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is still not working if I put in `mydomain.com/es/`.

Comment: Hmmm... strange it works for me. Also note that I didn't use the same controller as you. I have changed that now.

Comment: Yeah I had noticed that. I will try it out again in a few minutes to confirm that there is nothing else funky going on. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, I had a typo. Sorry to make you question your code. I should have been more careful.